# c++、テンプレートのtypenameとclassの違いについて知りたい

Tags: c++

(参考書:明解c++中級編425ページ)
　参考書のほうで`class`と`typename`についての言葉の違いの説明がなく混乱しているので説明をお願いしたいです、ググりましたがいろんなことを言っているサイトがあってどれがほんとなのかわかりません。`class`と`typename`のどちらも使い方が同じというサイトもあるので混乱しています。
　また、`for`文に`typename`という記述を入れないとエラーになるのですがどうしてでしょうか？

```
    template<typename allocator>
        void put_string_vector(const vector<string, allocator>& v)
        {
            cout << "{";
            for (typename vector<string, allocator>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
                cout << " ";
                for (typename vector<string, allocator>::size_type j = 0; j < v[i].length(); j++) {
                    cout << v[i][j];
                }
                cout << "\" ";
            }
            cout << "}";
        }

        int main()
        {
            vector<string> s1(3);
            vector<string> s2;

            s2.push_back("ABC");
            s2.push_back("123");
            s2.push_back("XYZ");

            cout << " s1 =";
            put_string_vector(s1);
            cout << "\n";

            cout << "s2 = ";
            put_string_vector(s2);
            cout << "\n";



            _getch();
            return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> テンプレートのtypenameとclass違いついて知りたい

- 1) テンプレートパラメータの宣言（`template <～>`の中身）においては、`typename` と `class` の違いはありません。全く同じ意味になります。
- 2) テンプレートを使うときに、`typename` キーワードが必要になるケースがあります（後述）

簡単にまとめると「テンプレートで使うのは `typename` だけ」と考えておけば安心です。

---

> またfor文のtypenameは入れないとエラーになるのですがどうしてしょうか？

for文の構文としては下記の通りで、*XXX* 箇所には型の名前が要求されます。

```
for (XXX i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) { ... }
```

具体的な型としては `vector<string, allocator>::size_type` を指定したいのですが、このタイミングではC++コンパイラは `～::size_type` が「型の名前」なのか「変数の名前」なのかを判断できず(※)、プログラマが `typename` キーワードを明示して「これは型の名前ですよ」とC++コンパイラに伝える必要があります。

<del>もしC++11以降に対応したC++コンパイラを使っているならば、単に `auto` とだけ書けばOKです。</del>
（`auto i = 0`ではint型に推論されてしまうため、インデクスループに対しては利用推奨しません。）

※ C++言語仕様上は、型名／変数名を判断できないときは変数名を優先するというルールがあり、`typename` が無いときは変数名と判断してコンパイルエラーになります。

Comment: `auto i = 0`としてしまうと`int`になってしまい、`v.size()`と正常に比較できないことがあるので危険ではないでしょうか？

Comment: 言われてみればindex loopの場合 `auto` 推奨は不適切ですね... 仕様上は"unsigned integer type"なので `auto i = 0u` か `size_t i = 0` のほうがまだマシですが、突き詰めると元の表記に戻ってしいますね。

Comment: sayuri さん指摘をうけて回答調整しました。`decltype(v.size()) i = 0` という手も無くはないですが、さすがに意図を読み取りづらいですね。